# Prolog, Finding the best match

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching, intersection

I have several prolog facts:

```
relation('Kitchen', [item(spoon), item(fork),  item(knife)  ]).
relation('Lounge',  [item(sofa),  item(chair), item(table)  ]).
relation('Bedroom', [item(bed),   item(desk),  item(drawers)]).
```

And a list that is generated at runtime, for example:

```
[item(spoon), item(knife)]
```

From this list, in this case, I would like 'Kitchen' to be returned as it is the best match.

I think I need to use the `intersection/3` predicate to get a count of how many matches there are to the runtime list, so Kitchen would return 2 and the others would return 0, but I don't know a way of recursing through all the `relation/2` predicates and testing each one, before only returning the best match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is the one that cannot be improved: 
`\+ better_candidate(Goal,CurSolution)`. Of course, instead of a simple length comparison you can implement a more elaborate comparison technique.

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

relation('Kitchen', [item(spoon), item(fork),  item(knife)  ]).
relation('Lounge',  [item(sofa),  item(chair), item(table)  ]).
relation('Bedroom', [item(bed),   item(desk),  item(drawers)]).

best(X,Best) :-
    relation(Best,BestList), intersection(X,BestList,I),
    length(I,L),
    \+ better_candidate(X,L).

better_candidate(X,L) :-
    relation(C,CList), intersection(X,CList,CI),
    length(CI,CIL), CIL > L.
```